# NodeJS fs.rename always thrown an error

Tags: node.js, fs

I don't understand one thing with `fs.rename()`, why this code always throw an error?

The file is correctly renamed but each time i got this error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/path/to/file/example.log' -> '/path/to/file/example_1.log'`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mv = fs.rename('example.log', 'example_1.log', function(err) {

  if(err instanceof Error)
    throw err;

});
```

Comment: Maybe try checking whats in the directory before and after, you can do this easily with `fs.readdirSync()`.

Comment: Instead of just file name , give full path with file name which you want to reanme.

Comment: This code is simplified, i provide the full path of files. The old file exists, but not the new one.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your exact code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mv = fs.rename('example.log', 'example_1.log', function(err) {

  if(err instanceof Error)
    throw err;

});
```

(the only difference is adding the `fs` require).

Then I get the error when I don't have the file in the current directory.

But when I create example.log and run the program then I don't get any error and the file is renamed.

Of course next time I get the error again because I no longer have the file with the original name.

Are you sure that it doesn't work for you?

By the way, instead of

```
if (err instanceof Error)
```

you may want to use:

```
if (err)
```

Just in case that your error is not the instance of Error but still is defined (this can be true while using some modules).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have fixed the code, i already use `var fs = require('fs');`. I had forgotten to put in on. Currently the code work perfectly this is why i don't understand this error.